# bash - Printing out the history of commands in bash (No awk or sed)

Tags: linux, bash, command, history

**Tried finding an answer here but can't. There was a duplicate question but all answers were with awk and sed which I'm not allowed to use! So once again, I ask you to help me.**

Basically I need to write a script that prints out the history of all used commands in the linux terminal. The commands are saved in a file which is put as the first argument of the script. Command "/bin/bash" equals bash so we don't mix things up. So, the print out should be sorted from commands with most occurrences to commands with least occurrences. Those with the same number of occ should be sorted in alphabetical order.

And, if we put switch -n the script only prints out the first n commands.
And with switch -p we also include the commands that are part of the pipeline.

Example of history.txt;

1. ls -al
2. bash
3. cat datoteka.txt
4. cat d.txt | sort | less
5. /bin/bash

What the script should print out;

- ./hstat.sh history.txt

  1. bash 2
  2. cat 2
  3. ls 1

As I'm fairly new to BASH programming and not really good at it, I would love some help with this. Where to start, some useful examples, maybe some code or even a lot of it :P Of course, with explanation or else it would be useless for me to just copy it.

Comment: `history |awk '{ print $2 }'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head` is a start

Comment: @Biffen you have to "normalize" the 2nd field so that `bash` and `/bin/bash` group together. See the duplicate, where I used `basename` for this.

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, there are a few issues. A hard one would be what to do with relative paths.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention. We MUST NOT use awk or sed. So that's a bummer. But thanks for marking this as a duplicate question. Will try to find my answer there. Cheers!

Comment: Just changing some comment will not help to reopen the question. You should at least **show** as much effort in your question you put into solving it yourself as you expect others to put into their answers. If you really want to be a programmer, you should learn one thing pretty fast: We are a bit pretentious when asked for help. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.